# How to open new form without creating new file c++/cli

Tags: forms, c++-cli

I wonder it is possible to create new form without creating new .h file, e.g. by pressing button on one form it opens another in new window.

Comment: The Winforms designer generates a .h file.  You don't have to use the designer, you can also write the class yourself.  But given that you had the ask the question, it probably is better if you don't.  Don't sweat the small stuff.

Comment: It still would be nice to know